# Model problems when using MVC

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Iv made a website in mvc and in the navbar i changed the code that allows MVC to show either a signin button (if user not logged in) or their name (if they are).

When the user clicks sign in a popup will show to allow them to login and this works fine, once the user logs in the username is displayed.

The problem arises when i click the username in the navbar. It should take me to the manage index page but instead gives me the error below:

```
Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
'Website.Models.IndexViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type
 'Website.Models.LoginViewModel'.
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out whats gone wrong (i am new to MVC as iv just moved from webforms).

I just want it to go to the manage page. I have included code from files i think will help people debug this error. If any others are need please just ask.

**_LoginPartial.cshtml**

```
@using CoffeePixel.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@model LoginViewModel

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <!-- add a clopasable pill type thing here to allow users to navigate the members area-->
                @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
        </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <style>
        #topHead .signin-dd form button:after {
            border: none !important;
        }

    </style>
    <!-- SIGN IN -->
    <div class="pull-right nav signin-dd">
        <a id="quick_sign_in" href="page-signin.html" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span class="hidden-xs"> Sign In</span></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="quick_sign_in" style="-moz-min-width: 200px; -ms-min-width: 200px; -o-min-width: 200px; -webkit-min-width: 200px; min-width: 200px;">

            <h4 class="text-center">Sign In</h4>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Username or Email" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group">

                    <!-- password -->
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    <!-- submit button -->
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign In</button>
                    </span>

                </div>

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <!-- remmember -->
                    <label>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe) Remember me &bull; <a href="@Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Account")">Forgot password?</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
            }

            <hr />
            <section id="socialLoginForm">
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Account/_ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml", new ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
            </section>
            <p class="bottom-create-account">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Register", "Account")">Not Registered?</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
            <!-- /SIGN IN -->
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Layout.cshtml (navbar snippet)**

```
<!-- Top Bar -->
    <header id="topHead">
        <div class="container">

            <!-- PHONE/EMAIL -->
            <span class="quick-contact pull-left">
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 1800-555-1234 &bull;
                <a class="hidden-xs" href="mailto:mail@yourdomain.com">mail@domain.com</a>
            </span>
            <!-- /PHONE/EMAIL -->
            <!-- LANGUAGE -->
            <div class="btn-group pull-right hidden-xs">
                <button class="dropdown-toggle language" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <img src="/Assets/images/flags/us.png" width="16" height="11" alt="EN Language" /> English <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="/Assets/images/flags/us.png" width="16" height="11" alt="EN Language" /> [US] English
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="/Assets/images/flags/de.png" width="16" height="11" alt="DE Language" /> [DE] German
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="/Assets/images/flags/fr.png" width="16" height="11" alt="FR Language" /> [FR] French
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="/Assets/images/flags/ru.png" width="16" height="11" alt="RU Language" /> [RU] Russian
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /LANGUAGE -->

            <!-- CART MOBILE BUTTON -->
            <a class="pull-right" id="btn-mobile-quick-cart" href="shop-cart.html"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
            <!-- CART MOBILE BUTTON -->
            <!-- LINKS -->
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            <div class="pull-right nav hidden-xs">
                <a href="@Url.Action("About", "Home")"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> About</a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Contact", "Home")"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Contact</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /LINKS -->

        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- /Top Bar -->
```

The controler

```
//
        // GET: /Manage/Index
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message)
        {
            ViewBag.StatusMessage =
                message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetTwoFactorSuccess ? "Your two-factor authentication provider has been set."
                : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
                : message == ManageMessageId.AddPhoneSuccess ? "Your phone number was added."
                : message == ManageMessageId.RemovePhoneSuccess ? "Your phone number was removed."
                : "";

            var model = new IndexViewModel
            {
                HasPassword = HasPassword(),
                PhoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
                TwoFactor = await UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
                Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
                BrowserRemembered = await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId())
            };
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: You mixing up your logic and difficult to understand exactly what your trying to do with this and to follow your code. The conditional logic should be in the menu, not in the login page, but you need to pass a model to the partial `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", new LoginViewModel)` otherwise the model passed is the model in the main view.

Comment: thanks! moving the logic to the Layout worked!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using the IndexViewModel as a property in LoginViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mostly likely in the second view. You should make sure that the manage index page's model is of type CoffeePixel.Models.IndexViewModel.

I assume you have at the top of the page:

```
@model LoginViewModel
```

If so replace it with:

```
@model IndexViewModel
```

Comment: This will not work because i have to use the loginviewmodel so that users can login.

Comment: Can you please include the Index method in the Manage controller you are calling and the top of the Manage Index view so I can help.